# Jgroup examples

Tags: java, jgroups

Is there a website which shows any jgroup code examples? The tutorial and manual on jgroups.org is not very good, and several cursory searches via Google, does not come up with much. I'm looking for examples of serializing objects and sending them over the channel to another JVM, etc.

Thanks in advance,

--Justin Richard Bleistein

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked out the new tutorial at http://www.jgroups.org/tutorial-3.x/html/index.html ? It shows how to send (string) messages between cluster nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note .. if you are looking for simple and fast 1:N remoting and serialization give
http://code.google.com/p/fast-cast/ a try. I am actively supporting it in case of problems. It's order of a magnitude faster, especially when it comes to remote calls and serialization.